# How to add padding using Media query in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to add padding according to the screen size of the user but on adding this code it is showing invalid constant value, can somebody please suggest me the alternative or a better solution.

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10),
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove `const` and you should be good to go.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10),
```

Comment: what should i do if i need to make a padding for only one side?

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti Use `EdgeInsets.only(left: 8)`

Comment: i ment using MediaQuery

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti Could you please post a separate question with more detail?

Comment: here you are my question :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61471006/how-to-add-a-mediaquerydata-to-a-spacific-padding?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @MariamAlbarghouti Do let me know if the solution added by me didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10), // error
```

var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;//can be used globally and similarly with height to.

```
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:width /10,), //after removing const
```

Comment: The right code is:  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
            )

Answer (score 0):

padding: EdgeInsets.only (left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10);

if you need to make a padding for only one side