# how to add a MediaQueryData to a spacific padding?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

**How to add a specific padding to bottom using MediaQueryData ?**

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom:8.0,
                ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

And to get width and height of the device screen:

```
mediaQueryData.size.width;
mediaQueryData.size.height;
```

Then you can do something like this

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    bottom: mediaQueryData.size.height * 0.05 // means 5% of screen height
  ), 
)
```

Comment: no it does not work,i have tried this way ,thanks for your effort

Comment: Can you add more details? Maybe you are mixing const with non-const variables and that's why it doesn't work. I have tried this, and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0,))
```

Using this method at BuildContext time may help you

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add spacing from the bottom and you're using a wrong widget for that, you should either use a `SizedBox` or provide a dummy child to your `Padding`.

For instance:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SomeWidget(),
    SizedBox(height: 20), // provides padding from bottom
  ],
)
```

If this isn't something you're looking for, I request you to update your question by adding more details of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score -2):

Padding widget always takes a const value in flutter and MediaQuery based value is not treated as constant.
So in case you need to provide a bottom padding add SizedBox widget below your widget to create the required free space as follows:

```
SizedBox(
height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
),
```

So this will give a space equivalent to one tenth of the screen height. Likewise you can adjust padding by changing the multiplication factor.